# c++ call linux commands forks childs

Tags: c++, linux, fork, wget

using linux commands in my c++ program. Trying to download a url from a list of arrays, once one download finishes, the next to start.... currently only downloads the first location in the array, then stops.

Does somebody see the error i'm doing?

```
// Begin the downloading process
pid_t child = 0;
child = fork();

if ( child < 0)
{
    cout << "Process Faileld to Fork<<endl;
    return 1;
}
if (child == 0)
    {
        wait(NULL);
    }
else
{
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfDownloads; i++)
    {
    execl("/usr/bin/wget", "wget",locations[i], NULL);  
    }
}
```

trying to download something with the command wget, but i get an error

Comment: Can you please provide a complete compilable example - then I might actually try your code instead of ignoring your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`execl` replaces the currently running process by the started process. So your loop body is only run once. You should put the `fork()` inside the loop, assuming you want to fork off `numberOfDownloads` instances of `wget`. (but be careful with such things)

Otherwise, use `system()`, which will not terminate your process but return to your loop after `wget` exits. Or `popen()`, if you need more control over the process and want to read `wget` output, without having to do all the I/O heavylifting yourself.

Comment: Or even do HTTP requests using the `libcurl` library, without `wget`